# How to quickly populate a combobox with database data (VCL)

Tags: database, delphi, combobox, dataset, lookup

I have read all sorts of documents across the web about what should be a farly common and painless implementation. Since I have found no consistent and slick reply (even the Embarcadero website describes some properties wrong!) I am going to post a "short" howto.

Typical, frequent use case: the developer just wants to painlessy show a couple of database-extracted information in a combo box (i.e. a language selection), get the user's choice out of it and that's it.

Requirements:

1. Delphi, more or less any version. VCL is covered.
2. A database table. Let's assume a simple table with an `id` and `value` fields.
3. A DataSet (including queries and ClientDataSets).
4. A DataSource linked to the DataSet.
5. A TDBLookupComboBox linked to the DataSource that shall show a list of values and "return" the currently selected id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, we decide whether the sort order is the one we want or not and if all the items in that table must be shown. Most often, a simple `ORDER BY` clause or a DataSet index will be enough. In case it's not, we may add a `sort_order` field and fill it with integers representing our custom sort order. In case we want to show just some items, we add a `visible` or `enabled` field and use it in our SQL. Example:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM my_database_table
WHERE visible = 1
ORDER BY sort_order
```

I have defined `visible` as INTEGER and checking it against `1` and not `TRUE` because many databases (including the most used SQLite) have little support for booleans.

Then an optional but surprisingly often nice idea: temporarily add a TDBGrid on the form, link it to the same TDataSource of the TLookupComboBox and check that you actually see the wanted data populate it. In fact it's easy to typo something in a query (assuming you are using a SQL DataSet) and get no data and then you are left wondering why the TDBLookupComboBox won't fill in.
Once seen the data correctly show up, remove the grid.

Another sensible idea is to use ClientDataSets for these kinds of implementations: due to how they work, they will "cache" the few rows contained in your look ups at program startup and then no further database access (and slowdown and traffic) will be required.

Now open the TDBLookupComboBox properties and fill in only the following ones:

`ListSource` (and *not* `DataSource`): set it to the TDataSource connected to the DataSet you want to show values of.
`ListField`: set it to the field name that you want the user to see. In our demo's case it'd be the `value` field.
`KeyField`: set it to the field name whose value you want the program to return you. In our demo it'd be the `id` field.

Don't forget to check the TabOrder property, there are still people who love navigating through the controls by pressing the `TAB` key and nothing is more annoying than seeing the selection hopping around randomly as your ComboBox was placed last on the form despite graphically showing second!

If all you need is to show a form and read the TDBLookupComboBox selected value when the user presses a button, you are pretty much sorted.
All you'll have to do in the button's OnClick event handler will be to read the combo box value with this code:

```
SelectedId := MyCombo.KeyValue;
```

Where `SelectedId` is any variable where to store the returned value and `MyCombo` of course is the name of your TDBLookupComboBox. Notice how KeyValue will not contain the text the user sees onscreen but the value of the `id` field we specified in `KeyField`. So, if our user selected database row was:

```
id= 5
value= 'MyText'
```

MyCombo.KeyValue shall contain `5`.

But what if you need to dynamically update stuff on the form, depending un the combo box user selection? There's no `OnChange` event available for our TDBLookupComboBox! Therefore, if you need to dynamically update stuff around basing on the combo box choices, you apparently cannot. You may try the various "OnExit" etc. events but all of them have serious drawbacks or side effects.
One possible solution is to create a new component inheriting from TDBLookupComboBox whose only task is to make public the hidden OnChange event. But that's overkill, isn't it?

There's another way: go to the **DataSet** your TDBLookupComboBox is tied to (through a DataSource). Open its events and double click on its `OnAfterScroll` event.
In there you may simulate an OnChange event pretty well.
For the sake of demonstration, add one integer variable and a TEdit box to the form and call them: `SelectedId` and `EditValue`.

```
procedure TMyForm.MyDataSetAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  SelectedId : integer;

begin
  SelectedId := MyDataSet.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
  EditValue.Text := MyDataSet.FieldByName('value').AsString;
end;
```

That's it: you may replace those two demo lines with your own procedure calls and whatever else you might need to dynamically update your form basing on the user's choices in your combo box.

A little warning: using the DataSet `OnAfterScroll` has one drawback as well: the event is called more often than you'd think. In example, it may be called when the dataset is opened but also be called more than once during records navigation. Therefore your code must deal with being called more frequently than needed.

At this point you might rub your hands and think your job is done!

Not at all! Just create a short demo application implementing all the above and you'll notice it lacks of an important finishing touch: when it starts, the combo box has an annoying "blank" default choice. That is, even if your database holds say 4 choices, the form with show an empty combo box selected value at first.
How to make one of your choices automatically appear "pre-selected" in the combo box as you and your users expect to?

Simple!

Just assign a value to the KeyValue property we already described above.
That is, on the `OnFormCreate` or other suitable event, just hard-code a choice like in example:

```
MyCombo.KeyValue := DefaultId;
```

For example, by using the sample database row posted above, you'd write:

```
MyCombo.KeyValue := 5;
```

and the combo box will display: "MyText" as pre-selected option when the user opens its form.

Of course you may prefer more elegant and involved ways to set a default key than hard-coding its default value. In example you might want to show the first alphabetically ordered textual description contained in your database table or whatever other criterium. But the basic mechanic is the one shown above: obtain the key / id value in any manner you want and then assign it to the `KeyValue` property.

Thank your for reading this HowTo till the end!

Comment: Thanks, you helped me out